# Statistical power analysis in Python for Design Experiment problem

Tags: python, experiment-design, statistical-power

I'm diving into some design of experiment studies based on [Design and Analysis of Experiments, 9th Edition by  Montgomery](https://www.wiley.com/en-ad/Design+and+Analysis+of+Experiments,+9th+Edition-p-9781119320937). I've had some questions about the first time I faced power analysis in the book, but I decided to carry on even so and hope my mind would clear out after more examples. Sadly, it just got worst, and now I have some serious questions about it, that I just can't find the answer anywhere else.

So, to give context, I'm performing all the analysis of experiments in Python, using some ready-to-go packages, and sometimes building the whole thing from scratch. Python does a good job, but in some cases, it's more reliable to code on my own than trust in the ready-to-go packages, as they don't offer the full support in some cases (i.e. power analysis).

More recently, I faced a problem with two factors (material type and temperature), each one with three levels. Plus, there are four observations within each group (4 repeated measures).

**My questions are:**

1. How do I calculate the needed amount of repeated measures that will return the desired power (i.e. greater than 80%)?
2. What variables should be taken into account to perform the power analysis?
3. The example here brings factors that are quantitative (temperature) and qualitative (material type). This difference seems relevant to me, but how should it be addressed during the power analysis? I mean, the power analysis method would be different if both factors were qualitative/quantitative?

In the book, the power analysis is done in JMP software, considering 3 or 4 repeated measures (sample sizes), with the last one being the best choice. Plus, there are different power results in the same analysis: interception, main effects, interactions and quadratic terms. Below goes some screenshots of the data table, ANOVA table, and Power Analysis made on JMP software.

Could someone please help me out in clarifying such a matter? Again, how do I calculate the ideal number of replications (sample size) for this type of design?

In the textbook's example, the power analysis is done after the experiment is complete. In my case, I would like to know the ideal amount of replicates (sample size) before the experiment starts, so I can design it properly in advance. Thanks very much to those souls that help me.

The first image shows the data collection table plus ANOVA results. The image below has two power analyses: the first one with 3 replicates, and the last one with 4 replicates.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is Dr. Montgomery's textbook?

Comment: @JeremyMiles it is Design and Analysis of Experiments, 9th Edition. This example can be found on page 183, in the 5.3 The Two-Factor Factorial Design session.

Comment: I've edited the question to include that information.